# vim typing error statistics - faster typing

Tags: vim

I use VIM to write code. I am not an experienced (yet) in [touch typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing) so I would like to put more stress in learning the keys that I mistype the most, apart of daily practice and TT drills.

Is there a way to get some stats about the typing errors? For example:

```
- "o" was changed to "p" 9 times
- "A" was changed to "a" 8 times
...
```

I am aware that it might be hard to define what is an error and what is not, so I need only some rough stats

Comment: In case if you would have used global or substitute command, you can get info abut them in history command. You can write a function to store the count of each unique changes in a register. It would be difficult to monitor each an every change.